# How to connect to GPRS programmatically in C# Win CE 5

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-ce

I am trying to automatically start the GPRS connection after device boot complete. How can I do this in Win CE 5 using C#?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called the Connection Manager. The documentation is here:

[MSDN documentation on Connection Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb840031.aspx)